# c# Iterate mehods in class to see if a method is being called

Tags: c#, class

The basic question is how can I determine if a certain string is contained in each method of a class?

We have a requirement that all methods in a certain class are making a logging call.  I want to iterate through the methods in this class and see if each methods is making this call.  I know I can use reflection to iterate the methods in a class, but how could I get the code in each method so I can do an IndexOf() ?

Ok, some more info.
Only certain methods need to call the logger (determined by me)  We want to be able to make sure that all methods either call the logger, have the logger called that is commented out so that we can run a program and determine what new methods have been added that don't have the logger called or commented out logger call.  Each month a group will determine if a method merits logging or not.
I am just trying to come up with an automated way to show all methods where logging has or has not been addressed.

Comment: on what do you want to call `IndexOf()`?

Comment: do you want to check if the the methods in your class are calling the logger by executing (invoking) the methods?

Comment: Why not mock the logger and write test cases?

Comment: Have to agree with Ritch -- if there's a requirement for every method (say N methods) to make such a call, there are N tests to write.

Comment: @Devendra, I want to get the text of a mehtod and call methodText.IndexOf("MyLogger.Log")

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into Post Sharp - http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp - or some other Aspect Oriented Programming framework.  This would allow you to attach the logging to the methods once and not have to do it in each method.

Comment: I have added some more info.  Every method does not need to log, only some determined by a supervisor.  I need to automatically see if...please see comments on my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don’t want to write all the code from scratch as a standalone program. For similar checks, you should probably write just a custom rule for [FxCop/Code Analysis tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/). That would be much easier, plus you can use the infrastructure around, like automatic checking on commit etc.

Comment: Morm, I hadn't thought about fxcop.  Do you know if you can create a rule that says all method in a class must call another method?

Comment: @TPSpencer - Sure, you write a rule which receives every class and you can then process all methods in the class to check whatever you want. The advantage to writing everything from the scratch is that you get much better (preprocessed) data structures. See e.g. http://www.toolheaven.net/post/Custom-FxCop-rules.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To get all the public instance methods in a class using reflection, just do:

```
MethodInfo[] minfos = typeof(MyType).GetMethods();
foreach (MethodInfo mi in minfos)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Public instance method: " + mi.Name);
}
```

if you need to also get the static or private method, you'll need to use the other `GetMethods` overload, like this:

```
MethodInfo[] minfos = typeof(ConfigurationItemType).GetMethods(
   BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | 
   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: sweko, thanks, I know how to get all methods in a class.  I need to know if a certain mehtod is being called in those methods.  Please re-read my question, as I have posted some more info.

Comment: It appears that you want to look at the source of the method, even more, at the comments in the source. Maybe StyleCop can help you with something like this, as it analyzes the source files, but you'll need to develop some custom rules.

Comment: Thanks SWeko, I will look into SyleCop.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** [ActiveSharp](http://activesharp.codeplex.com/) seems to be doing what you need programmatically.
Check the example under "Inspecting MSIL at Runtime (lightweight alternative to FxCop)" on [this page](http://activesharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20ActiveSharp%20as%20a%20Unit%20Test%20Tool&referringTitle=Home)

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodToLookAt = ....; // obtain this via normal reflection, e.g. Type.GetMethod

ActiveSharp.Inspection.MethodInspector ins = new MethodInspector(methodToLookAt, false);

// what are all the methods that it (directly) calls?
IEnumerable<MethodBase> callees = ins.AllCalledMethods;
```

If you want to do it the hard way and try inspecting the CIL via reflection, you can try reading [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2005/10/02/476242.aspx)

Comment: Thanks paolo, I will check it out.

Comment: Wow, that is exacly what I was looking for! Thanks paolo.

Comment: @TPSpencer you're welcome. I've learned something new too, so +1 for the question.